# How to append two element in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, angularjs

I am pushing element in the array using javascript .

and i am getting output like this

```
["api", "management", "provision", "tenant", "external", "provider"]  => Correct
```

after pushing the data into array now i want append two element from the array **management** and **provision** and want output like this

```
["api", "management/provision", "tenant", "external", "provider"]
```

how would i do this ?

any example would be good for me

thanx in advance

Comment: Remove them both, concatenate the strings and then add the concatenated string back to the array. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to remove them both, join with `/` and put at the right place. You can do this in a few lines of code:

```
const input = ["api", "management", "provision", "tenant", "external", "provider"];
input.splice(1, 3, input.slice(1, 3).join('/'));
// now input contains ["api", "management/provision", "external", "provider"]
```

This can be further made more readable and reusable:

```
function mergeTerms(startIndex, endIndex, array) {
    const input = array.slice(0); // make a shallow copy of the array in order not to mutate it
    input.splice(startIndex, endIndex, input.slice(startIndex, endIndex).join('/'));
    return input;
}
```

and then:

```
mergeTerms(1, 3, input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say its the var array that holds the values.

```
var temp = array.splice(2,3);
array[1] = array[1]+"/"+temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function mergeArrayEntries(e1, e2, arr) {
var index = -1;
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i] == e1) {
       index = i;
     }
     if (arr[i] == e2 && index > -1) {
       arr[index] = arr[index]+"/"+arr[i];
       arr.splice(i, 1);
     }
   }
}
```

this function searches for e1 and e2 in the arr and once found, it merges them to position of e1 and deletes e2 entry in arr.

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Not the nicest code, and not at all reusable, but will give you what you are looking for --- just another approach

```
var array = ["api", "management", "provision", "tenant", "external", "provider"];
var subArray = [];
subArray.push(array[1]);
subArray.push(array[2])
array.splice(1, 2);
subArray = subArray.join("/")
array.splice(1, 0, subArray);
```